# jQuery: ajax call not executed on form submit event unless I have a alert call after it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I'm doing some modifications to an existing form on web application. I can't have access to the form's code, but I can add scripts to the page, so I'm doing some customizations with the help of jQuery.

So, right now I have something like this:

```
jQuery( "#new_user" ).submit(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

var fullname = jQuery("#user_name").val();
var email = jQuery("#email_primary").val();
var company = jQuery("#contact_customer").val();

jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url:"https://server.com/script.php",
        data: {"fullname": fullname, "email": email, "company": company},
        success: function(response){
        alert("json says " +response.res);
        }
});
    alert("hello");
});
```

Now, this works fine. I'm basically intercepting the form submission.

Problem is, **the ajax call is only executed if I keep the alert() call in there**, something obviously I do not want, it's just for debug. If I remove the alert() call, the form will submit but the ajax call will not work as it should. I have access to the web server that is supposed to receive the JSONP request, and it doesn't even get there.

The second alert actually never gets executed, but actually I don't need anything there, I just need to receive the GET on the webserver.

I have tried to add async:false to ajax() options, but no luck.

I'm a bit puzzled, and researched/experimented about it quite a bit. any tip appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the form from submitting, otherwise the ajax request will be cancelled

```
jQuery( "#new_user" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault()
    jQuery.ajax(...);
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Actually I had preventDefault() too, no help. I just completed the code now.

Answer (score 1):

And you wanted to submit the form on ajax success, right?

```
jQuery( "#new_user" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var self = jQuery(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url:"https://server.com/script.php",
        data: {"fullname": fullname, "email": email, "company": company},
        success: function(response){
            alert("json says " +response.res);
            self.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not mandatory, it's fine to always submit, submission in this case doesn't need to depend on success of that call.

Comment: maybe this then `complete: function(){ self.submit(); }`

Comment: I don't think I need complete because I don't care if the ajax call is successful or not. Meaning, e.g. if the web server that gets the ajax request is down, the submit should happen anyway.

Comment: I do need for the ajax call to be at least attempted, that's what's not happening if I remove the alert() after it.

Comment: Complete fires whether request was success or not. All that's left is to guard from new submit causing another ajax request -  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/xNbKQ/

Comment: yes it does, but on its own. I guess the main problem here is that there seem to be other bindings on the site interfering. Because if I add event.stopImmediatePropagation() before .ajax, this code works. The problem is that other code (like validation) will not work.

Comment: Branch the flow based on whether the ajax has been attempted.  If not, then stop propagation, prevent default, or whatever it takes.  Then in the ajax complete, set attribute and submit as normal (without prevention of normal events).  Make sense?  Does it work?

Comment: It does work, this is great progress, thanks. However, the ajax call is not the last action being performed, the validation is happening afterwards. I'm now trying to workaround that.